# SQL - Find duplicate records that meet certain conditions

Tags: sql, duplicates, where-clause

I have the table below and I am trying to get duplicates using the `external_id` column with `WHERE` clauses on other fields also. Thus I am trying to get rows which have the same external_id, but which also have the same user and same team. From the table below I am trying to get the external_ids of records 1 and 3.

`id     | external_id |   user       | team
--------+-------------+----------------+------------
     1  | 5          | A            | alpha
     2  | 6          | B            | beta
     3  | 5          | A            | alpha
     4  | 7          | B            | sigma
     5  | 5          | A            | delta`

So far I managed just to get duplicates on the external_id fields using the query below and I am getting records: 1, 3 and 5 as a count grouped by the `external_id` column. I do not want record 5 and I also want the query to return the whole rows and not as counts.

```
           select 
              external_id, count(external_id) 
            from 
              table 
            group by 
              external_id 
            having 
              count(external_id)>1;
```

I dont know how I can further filter the results to get only the duplicate records were the user and the team are also identical. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for all three fields to be identical, add the two additional fields to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  external_id, user, team, COUNT(external_id) 
FROM
  table 
GROUP BY
  external_id, user, team
HAVING
  COUNT(external_id) > 1
```

This way records with identical `external_id` but different `user` and/or `team` wouldn't even make it into the same group, and would be filtered by the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery on the having  count >1 eg

```
  select * from my_table  
  where  (external_id, user,team) in (
    select external_id ,   user ,team
    from my_table 
    group by external_id ,   user ,team 
    having count(*) >1

  )
```

or you can do with an inner join on subselect

```
select * from my_table  a
inner join (
   select external_id ,   user ,team
    from my_table 
    group by external_id ,   user ,team 
    having count(*) >1 ) t on t.external_id = a.external_id 
                 and t.user = a.user and t.team = a.team
```

Comment: The engine might take care of this behind the scenes depending on what you are using but I would select null on the inner query.  Also depending on the engine it might run better as a join.

Comment: @JoeC   correct .. comment  .. i have update the answer  also with your suggestion  ..